# How to install syck 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, syck

I'm getting an error installing syck on Ubuntu 15.04. Building the native extensions fails:

```
Installing syck 1.0.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/markus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150618-8242-1z0c5iw.rb extconf.rb
checking for st.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bytecode.c
compiling implicit.c
compiling token.c
token.re: In function ‘sycklex_yaml_utf8’:
token.re:541:36: warning: variable ‘lvl’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
compiling rubyext.c
rubyext.c:31:20: error: field ‘hash’ has incomplete type
     struct RHash   hash;
                    ^
rubyext.c: In function ‘syck_seq_initialize’:
rubyext.c:1529:15: warning: variable ‘node’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     SyckNode *node;
               ^
Makefile:237: recipe for target 'rubyext.o' failed
make: *** [rubyext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/markus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@mygemset/gems/syck-1.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/markus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@mygemset/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/syck-1.0.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing syck (1.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install syck -v '1.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Does someone have an idea what the issue is and how to fix it?

Comment: Seeing the same issue on openSUSE 13.2 (x86_64).

Comment: The fix for me was to not install syck `1.0.1`. It works just fine with `1.0.5`. Although there seem to be some API changes between those versions unfortunately which may break things.

Comment: I was trying to install openproject. It seems to depend on syck 1.0.1. It appears to have a problem with Ruby 2.2. I solved it by using Ruby 2.1 instead.

Comment: Ah thanks! Yes, it depends on syck 1.0.1. If you update it to 1.0.5 an OpenProject migration will fail, though. I'll see if I can fix this. If not I'll also simply use Ruby 2.1, I guess.